# Gulp task running twice

Tags: javascript, gulp

After reading through a few related topics I still can't figure out what's causing gulp running a task twice.

This is the only task running twice:

```
const acf = "_sass/_admin/acf.scss";
const output = "./assets";

gulp.task("acf", () => {
    return gulp.src(acf)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer("last 2 versions", "> 5%"))
        .pipe(concat("acf.min.css"))
        .pipe(minify({ compatibility: '*' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Another task which is handling a sibling file is running only once:

```
const gutenberg = "_sass/_admin/gutenberg.scss";

gulp.task("gutenberg", () => {
    return gulp.src(gutenberg)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer("last 2 versions", "> 5%"))
        .pipe(concat("gutenberg.min.css"))
        .pipe(minify({ compatibility: '*' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Writing to the same DIR that another task is watching does not seem to be the issue.

See this handler:

```
gulp.task("default", done => {
    browserSync.init({
        open: false,
        proxy: siteURL
    });

    gulp.watch(acf, gulp.series("acf"));
    gulp.watch(gutenberg, gulp.series("gutenberg"));
    done();
});
```

What am I missing? How do I make sure that the ACF task only runs once?